# Can a thief steal if he can't equip the item?

Tags: munchkin

If a thief is already wearing a hat in Munchkin, is it possible that he can attempt to steal someone else's hat, even if he can't wear it? What about if he sells it immediately?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [rules](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/rules/munchkin_rules.pdf):

> All Items you have in play are considered "carried." Items that are actually giving you a bonus are "equipped."
>
> Anyone can *carry* any Item (except for extra Big items), but you may *equip* only one Headgear, [etc.] ... If you are carrying two Headgear cards, for instance,
> you can equip only one of them at a time.

This means that even if an item can't be equipped (because you already have an item equipped in that slot, or any other reason), it can still be carried, so a thief can still steal it and just carry it.

Comment: Oh! Is that where he plays it sideways and then it gives no bonus?

Comment: Yes, "You should indicate Items that are not equipped by turning the cards sideways."

Comment: Alright! I'm gonna leave it open for a bit see what else I can gather but thank you very much. :)

Comment: I concur. Nothing in the ability says the thief can only steal items they can equip. If they don't want to equip the item, they may merely carry it.

Answer (score -3):

I found this on the munchkin forum.

> When the Item is stolen, it stays in play.

I guess this means in order to steal the item you must be able to keep it in play. If you have the open space, you can steal and sell immediately, but if you cannot keep it in play, you cannot steal.

http://forums.sjgames.com/showpost.php?p=1047228&

Comment: What's the "open space" to which you're referring?

Comment: I mean if you're already wearing a headgear, that is not open to wear another headgear.

Comment: @Scalia Carried items are in play but not equipped. By staying in play it means it doesn't go into the hand of the thief, not that it must be immediately equipped.